# Handle date selection in MatDatepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I have mat-datepicker with own button(s) in my (template driven) form.

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        name="validFrom"
        [disabled]="isReadOnly"
        [(ngModel)]="validFrom"
        required
        (dateChange)="validFromChanged($event)"
        (dateInput)="validFromChanged($event)"
        [matDatepicker]="validFromPicker">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="validFromPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #validFromPicker>
        <mat-datepicker-actions>
          <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="setToday()">Today</button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
        </mat-datepicker-actions>
        <mat-calendar (click)="onCalendarClick($event)"></mat-calendar>
      </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there any way to handle date change event (when user clicks on some date in calendar) before is clicked on Apply button?

How can I handle onCalendarClick()? Because it does not work in my case.

Or, is there any other option how can I add custom button "Today" and do not prevent automatic close when date is selected on the calendar?

Comment: I always check [the documentation first](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#input-and-change-events) but that's me...

Comment: What do you mean? dateChange, dateInput are fired AFTER apply button is clicked, so it does not solve my problem. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099766/angular-material-today-button/77051771#77051771)

Just use

```
<mat-datepicker #picker (opened)="getMonthView(picker)" 
                        (monthSelected)="getMonthView(picker)">
....
</mat-datepicker>
```

Well, what do you want to do when "click"? If it's change the date but not close use simply

```
  getMonthView(picker:any)
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.sub && this.sub.unsubscribe()
      this.sub=picker._componentRef?.instance._calendar
               .monthView.selectedChange.subscribe((res:any)=>{
                  this.date=res; //<--here store the "date"
                })
     })
  }
  setToday(picker:any)
  {
    picker._componentRef.instance._calendar.activeDate=this.date=new Date()
  }
```

[stackblitz in Angular 14](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2wkeka?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)

Comment: I would like to change date and close calendar, so user dont need to click twice - select date and confirm by apply button.

Comment: @kkthlv, simply add `picker.close()` after equal de date.